# Android: Layout Editor hide alignment arrows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I would like to be able to permanently hide the allignment arrows in the Layout Editor view in Android Studio 2.2. I tried searching through the options but found nothing. Is this possible?
[current layout editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mifjv.png) vs [Layout Editor I want to make permanet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rEd7.png)

Comment: But, they are there to help you.

Comment: I know, but when I zoom in on the screen to modify one area in particular it gets all messy and hard to see the overall aspect. It would be nice to have a way to disable it.

Comment: Alright. I think the Android Studio [feature request page](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Tools%20feature%20request) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, my Android Studio (Version 2.2 also) just show the arrows when i hover te mouse over the component, i don't remember of changing anything in this configuration

Comment: The arrows seem to be activated by a "onMouseHover" event on the layout and deactivated by a "onMouseHover" in the white space outside the displayed layout. If however you zoom in on a part of the layout, the second event never triggers so once they have been activated the arrows never disappear. I was hoping there would be an option to permanently get rid of them altogether.